Caching terminology
In docs sites, blogs, tools and on StackExchange, I often see various caching terms used interchangeably (though I suspect they differ).
Is there a theoretical difference between these terms:

Eviction
Invalidation
Expiry
Clearing / Purging / Removing


One difference is that some terms are more applicable than others depending on whether the cache is read-only data, write-through, or write-behind.
